# how to replace first <p> tag with <p property="v:street-address"> using xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, msxsl

This `xsl:apply-templates` instruction:

```
<xsl:if test="$item/tcm:Content/em:Office/em:Address">
    <address>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="renderhtml" select="$item/tcm:Content/em:Office/em:Address/node()" />
    </address>
</xsl:if>
```

produces:

```
<p>
    My Office Address
    <br />XXXX Road
    <br />XXXX District
    <br />XXXX, XXXX.
    <br />PO Box XXXX
</p>
```

Now I want to store the produced html in a variable and later call another template to replace the first `<p>` element with `<p property="v:street-address">`, so that it the final result would be:

```
<p property="v:street-address">
    My Office Address
    <br />XXXX Road
    <br />XXXX District
    <br />XXXX, XXXX.
    <br />PO Box XXXX
</p>
```

Please suggest!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0, you can only capture an output and apply templates to that output is if you are using a processor that supports [the `node-set()` function](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/07/16/nodeset.html).  Assuming that you are, you can do something like this:

```
<xsl:if test="$item/tcm:Content/em:Office/em:Address">
    <address>
      <xsl:variable name="addressHtml">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="renderhtml" 
                             select="$item/tcm:Content/em:Office/em:Address/node()" />
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($addressHtml)" 
                           mode="adjustAddressHtml" />
    </address>
</xsl:if>

...

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="adjustAddressHtml" name="Identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="adjustAddressHtml" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/" mode="adjustAddressHtml">
    <xsl:if test="p">
      <xsl:call-template name="Identity" />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not(p)">
      <xsl:call-template name="StartingP" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/p[1]" mode="adjustAddressHtml" name="StartingP">
    <p property="v:street-address">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="adjustAddressHtml" />
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: what is exslt here? what need to be declared as I am using xslt 1.0

Comment: `exslt` is just one of several namespaces that contain the `node-set()` function, depending on the processor. What XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: sorry for late response due to time difference, here is my top declaration
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:em="http://www.mycompany.com/tridion/schemas" xmlns:tcmse="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.1/TcmScriptAssistant" exclude-result-prefixes="em xlink tcmse tcm">

Comment: @ManojSingh What I'm asking is - what program, library, or framework are you using to execute the XSLT?

Comment: Ok, we are using xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt", I have used your logic in my code and working fine, now two things, 1) I need this to be implemented for first <p> tag only 2) If there is no <p> tag we need to add address data inside <p property="v:street-address"> adress........</p>, please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Without a source XML document provided it is difficult to give a complete answer, but **in general one can avoid the need of a two-pass transformation**.

**Instead, the XSLT code can be somethong as simple as**:

Somewhere:

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="renderhtml"
         select="$item/tcm:Content/em:Office/em:Address/>
```

Then:

```
 <xsl:template match="em:Address" mode="renderhtml">
  <address>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="renderhtml" select="node()" />
  </address>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="em:Address/node()" mode="renderhtml">
    <p>
     <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
      <xsl:attribute name="property">v:street-address</xsl:attribute>
     </xsl:if>
       <!-- The code that generates this:
        My Office Address
        <br />XXXX Road
        <br />XXXX District
        <br />XXXX, XXXX.
        <br />PO Box XXXX
         -->
    </p>
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: I can change "renderHtml" as this is common for other xslt, please suggest some specific solution for this

Comment: @ManojSingh You have failed to provide the necessary information to give you a confident answer: a description of the format of the input XML along with an example, and enough of your XSLT to understand how its working (preferably more than the 5 lines you gave us, plus the XSLT for the `renderHtml` mode. You have also failed to answer a very simple query for information that I asked you two hours ago.

Comment: @ManojSingh, I completely agree with JLRishe -- when you post *such* questions you inevitably receive *such* answers. Please, value the time of the readers.